# CoreData for Adding under an Object in Relationship

Tags: objective-c, ipad, core-data, nsmutablearray

This is probably easier for iPhone devs who are familiar with CoreData but i am not and would really like to know how to properly access my data within a crucial deadline.

This is what my core data is once its set to an `NSMutableArray` and pulled with NSLog

```
Questions List KM: (
    "<Question: 0x8589630> (entity: Question; id: 0x8588820 <x-coredata://FDC76465-4884-473A-B46A-3451BCB74F5C/Question/p1> ; data: {\n    orderID = 0;\n    project = \"0x818e300 <x-coredata://FDC76465-4884-473A-B46A-3451BCB74F5C/Project/p1>\";\n    question = \"What is ...? \";\n    strategy = \"<relationship fault: 0x8264930 'strategy'>\";\n})",
    "<Question: 0x85898d0> (entity: Question; id: 0x8588830 <x-coredata://FDC76465-4884-473A-B46A-3451BCB74F5C/Question/p2> ; data: {\n    orderID = 1;\n    project = \"0x818e300 <x-coredata://FDC76465-4884-473A-B46A-3451BCB74F5C/Project/p1>\";\n    question = \"How is ...? \";\n    strategy = \"<relationship fault: 0x826fa60 'strategy'>\";\n})",
    "<Question: 0x8589930> (entity: Question; id: 0x8588840 <x-coredata://FDC76465-4884-473A-B46A-3451BCB74F5C/Question/p3> ; data: {\n    orderID = 2;\n    project = \"0x818e300 <x-coredata://FDC76465-4884-473A-B46A-3451BCB74F5C/Project/p1>\";\n    question = \"Where is ...? \";\n    strategy = \"<relationship fault: 0x826c430 'strategy'>\";\n})"
)
```

I was able to easily pull this to an array with the below:

```
// fetch and sort questions
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Question"  inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [request setEntity:entity];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"orderID" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
    [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
    if (mutableFetchResults == nil) {
        // Handle the error.
        NSLog(@"No Results in Questions Array.");
    }

    [self setQuestionsList:mutableFetchResults];
```

Here is the Question.h or Question Definitions:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class Project, Strategy;

@interface Question : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * orderID;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * question;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Project *project;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *strategy;
@end

@interface Question (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addStrategyObject:(Strategy *)value;
- (void)removeStrategyObject:(Strategy *)value;
- (void)addStrategy:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeStrategy:(NSSet *)values;

@end
```

here is Strategy.h for definitions:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class Question;

@interface Strategy : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * strategy;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Question *question;

@end
```

You can see in the NsLog of the data that there are Three Questions

1. question = \"What is ...?
2. question = \"How is ...?
3. question = \"Where is ...?

It also shows that there is a Strategy Section in the Relationship:

```
strategy = \"<relationship fault: 0x826c430 'strategy'>\
```

What I need to be able to do is access this Strategy and Add a single Object to it of Type NSString.

Once assigned then i need to Pull as the Strategies to an NSMutableArray to be pushing into a UITableView.

I know this is a lot to take in but to an Apple Guru this probably sounds like Cake and Ice Cream.

If more Information is needed to answer, please let me know in the comments....a great StackOverflow member once told me

> "sometimes the hardest part is finding the right way to ask a
>   question."

Any Help is Much Appreciated!

Comment: It would help if you show the definitions of all your entities and relationships.

Comment: @MartinR How would I find those? I can see the tables....As well another developer on the project built the coredata originally and i have to plug into it.

Comment: There is probably a .h file for each entity, like "Question.h". You could show these.

Comment: Strategy.h is probably also needed. What do you mean by "Add a single Object to the strategy of Type NSString"?

Comment: Okay adding now...I mean, the Strategy Entity has one attribute called  "strategy" with attribute type NSString. So Im building another table right now called tools which has a relationship to strategies and I need to make sure the strategies are assigned to the right question and tools to the right strategy.(Thats a lot Sorry!)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33294/discussion-between-keeano-martin-and-martin-r)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand your question correctly, but accessing the strategies for
a question is simply done via the accessor methods.
(Note that `strategy` is a to-many relationship, so a better name would be `strategies`, and
I will use that here)

```
Question *theQuestion = ... //
NSSet *strategiesAsSet = theQuestion.strategies; // set of related Strategy objects
// or:
NSArray *strategiesAsArray = [theQuestion.strategies allObjects]; // array of related Strategy objects.
```

To add a strategy, you have to create the object:

```
Strategy *newStrategy = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Strategy" inManagedObjectContext:context];
```

and then set the relationship. You can ***either*** set

```
newStrategy.question = theQuestion;
```

***or*** alternatively,

```
[question addStrategyObject:newStrategy];
```

Due to the nature of *inverse relationships*, the these two operations are equivalent,
one implies the other.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a fetch request to populate an array with *all* of the Question entities and then using that to supply a table take a look at `NSFetchedResultsController` http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

It can be used very easily as a data source for a table view and won't load every entity of the requested type into memory at once. With three questions that may not matter but if you can add questions it may start to matter down the road.

Martin R has the right idea for when it comes to accessing the relationship between the two entities. Though if each question can have multiple strategies but each strategy can only have one question I'm not sure an entity is warranted. You might want to see about storing an `NSSet` of strings directly in an attribute of the Question entity. (I'm pretty sure you can set the attribute type to 'data' and store an array in it, but you would have to look that up to see how).

Comment: Using an NSFetchedResultsController is surely a good idea. - You *could* store a set of strings using a "transformable" attribute, but then you lose for example the ability to *search* for strings, so I would not recommend that.